# MS Access-Using value from a form in a calculated field of a table

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a text box in a form which accepts a date.
I have to use that date in the calculated expression in a field of a table.
Initially I have tried to use this statement in the calculated expression.

```
[Forms]![Input data form]![Text38]
```

But it shows that "The expression cannot be used because refers to another table".

How to access the value of the text box?

Comment: Is your calculated epression in the table itself, or in the record source for the form?

Comment: Never seen that error. Referencing in query to textbox on form works for me. Is the textbox bound and value saved to a table? Edit your question to post the full SQL statement for analysis.

Comment: @SandPiper the calculated expression is in the table.

Comment: @June7 I'm a noob in access,I can't understand your question. How to reference a query to textbox? The value is not saved to a table.

Comment: I just realized you said this calc is in a table Calculated type field. Cannot do that. Can reference textbox in calculation in a query or in the textbox of a report. So if your goal is to show this calculation in report output, either have to save to table or reference the form textbox in query or report textbox. And of course the form must be open when the query or report is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question. You have a table and you want to use a calculated field in it that references a value in a form.

You will not be able to do it that way. The reason you are getting an error is because the form data only exists when the form is running. If you used that expression in the record source query of the form, you would be ok.

You have a couple of choices depending on what you are trying to do with the data. If you REALLY NEED a calculated field in your table, you can use a form to make an UPDATE to another field in your table; then it is static data and your calculated control can work.

Another option is to have a separate table to store the user input value, then use a VIEW (QUERY in Access terminology) to join the data together and compute the result. Depending on why you are doing it, this is typically the method you want to go with.

If this does not answer your question and you have something more specific, I will try to tailor the answer more.

Comment: The understanding of my question by you is right. Can you explain the 1st option of creating a static data more detailly.

Comment: Sure. Say right now you have ColumnA. Make a ColumnB as well. Then, your calculated field is ColumnC = ColumnA + ColumnB (or whatever your expression is). Using your form, have the user input a valid piece of data, then use a button to execute the following SQL statement: `UPDATE TableName SET ColumnB = [Text38].Value WHERE 1=1;` That will set all current records' ColumnB to your user input. ColumnC will automatically calculate.

Comment: But it will set all the records of the columnB to the value...it will not look good..But its ok..Thank you.

Comment: Do you need this value for every record? If yes, then why does that not look good? Will this value change? Will multiple users be using this db and each will change this value? If users try to do this at same time, they will conflict with each other.

Comment: That will indeed set all records to the value. As I said, it depends on what you are really trying to do. If you are trying to get a different value for each record, I would recommend using a tabular form where the value of one textbox is calculated based on the value of the user input textbox.

Comment: What I'm doing is..I have a field named loss of pay in my table , In that field I have a calculated expression Gross salary*Loss of pay/No of days in a month. The date is inputted in the textbox of the input form. I have to use the date from the form to calculate the loss of pay field of the table. Making the same date to appear for all the records will not look good.

Comment: In that case, you definitely want to create a form that ties to your table. Use the TABLUAR layout. By using the record source for the form as your `MyTableName`, you can have a text box that has its record source as your ColumnB where the user can manually input the value. ColumnC can have the formula specified in the table itself.

Comment: The input date will be same for all the records..then why to store it in a column rather than using it directly in the calculated field.

Comment: If the input date is going to be the same for all records, then you are back to updating all records as I previously mentioned. Otherwise, you are still looking at using a tabular form, but just having a text box display the data. But you won't have it permanently saved in the table. If I had already answered your question, why did you mark it as unaccepted?